# ng-repeat not populating table data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The table should be populated with data taken from an array. The code before has worked on other applications, so I've copied over the script and for some reason the data isn't loading. No errors are showing in the console. The error must lie in the data not being found. Any ideas why?

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in patents">
    <td>{{x.id}} h</td>
    <td>{{x.applicationnumber}}</td>
    <td>{{x.clientref}}</td>
    <td>$ {{x.costtorenew}}</td>
    <td>{{x.renewalduedate}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(x.id)">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/list-patents', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/list-patents.htm',
        controller: 'patentCtrl'
    })

app.controller('patentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'loadPatents', function($scope, $http, loadPatents) {

var self = this;
self.patent={id:null,applicationnumber:'',clientref:'',costtorenew:'',renewalduedate:'',basketstatus:''};
self.patents=[];
self.remove = remove;

fetchAllPatents();

function fetchAllPatents(){
    loadPatents.fetchAllPatents()
        .then(
        function(d) {
            self.patents = d;
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while fetching Users');
        }
    );
    console.log(self.patents)
}

}]);
```

---

```
app.factory('loadPatents', function($http, $q) {

    var factory = {};

    var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/Sprint002b/restpatent/';

    factory.fetchAllPatents = function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
         $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI)
            .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while fetching Users');
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    return factory;
})
```

Comment: You are not using controllerAs syntax in the view I think.

Comment: In your controller you're getting data. right?

Comment: try `<tr ng-repeat="x in self.patents">`

Comment: For that you need to define controllerAs somewhere, like router or inside ng-controller, without that this won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using controllerAs in your view, try below code, If you're getting data in controller than this will work.

```
<body ng-controller="patentCtrl as p">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in p.patents">
    <td>{{x.id}} h</td>
    <td>{{x.applicationnumber}}</td>
    <td>{{x.clientref}}</td>
    <td>$ {{x.costtorenew}}</td>
    <td>{{x.renewalduedate}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(x.id)">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahhhh step in the right direction. So if the controller is receiving data, I need to use controllerAs? It's loading content (such as the button) but not the data itself

Comment: Yes, content will load because it's static content. You can check by using $scope in your controller in place of `self (var self = this;)`, then also it'll work

Comment: No it was down to my property names in the JSON file. It's all sorted now. Thank you for your time! I'll accept in a minute

Comment: Sure. Good Day.